# Toast does not show on screen

Tags: java, android, android-toast

I am sorry if it is a too simple question. I have searched everywhere, but could not find a solution. For about 3 days Toast does not show up on my app. I tried to do a lot of things.

- Change `makeText(this)` to `makeText(getApplicationContext())` or `makeText(getBaseContext())`
- Change position of the Toast and tried other solution on StackOverflow, but it did not appear.

Here is the code

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Great", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: where do you use this line?

Comment: Initially use Toast.LENGTH_LONG, just in case it is dismissing too early for you to see it ( I had that happen to me once)

Comment: Please post the code where and when you use that line.

Comment: Please post the code where your toast is used

Comment: Are you displaying toast in activity or in fragment??

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test string", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

The most important one , make sure your Android Notifications are on for your app, else the Toast will not be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Toast.makeText(yourActivity.this, "Try Toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And make sure you use the codes in the correct line.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "This is my Toast message!",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: The answer is not useful. The concerned person also implemented the solution, you can add more details to it.